# Can I count multiple columns with Group By?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a table with these columns:

```
s, s2, s3  
1, 2,  3  
4  
1, 3  
4, 2,  
2, 1  
3, 4  
4
```

I want to know how many times the unique values in column s appears in the columns s, s2 and s3.

So far I have:

```
$query = "SELECT s, COUNT(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY s";
```

This will give me:

```
1 - count 2  
2 - count 1  
3 - count 1  
4 - count 3
```

But I want to count the column s2 and s3 also so the outcome will be:

```
1 - count 3  
2 - count 3  
3 - count 3  
4 - count 4
```

Any idea how I must edit the query so I can count the columns s, s2 and s3 group by the values of column s?

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: You might want to redesign youe table with an M:N relationship and use `JOIN`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a UNION ALL for all the columns and then count them:

```
select
  t.s, count(*) counter
from (
  select s from tablename union all
  select s2 from tablename union all
  select s3 from tablename
) t
where t.s is not null
group by t.s
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C1FxXFnt97HkTWhfRXHNx/0).
Results:

```
| s   | counter |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   | 3       |
| 2   | 3       |
| 3   | 3       |
| 4   | 4       |
```

If in the columns `s2` and `s3` there are values that do not exist in the column `s` and you want them excluded, then instead of:

```
where t.s is not null
```

use

```
where t.s in (select s from tablename)
```

Comment: I use Union for the fiirst time and I must say, it looks pretty simple ... ;-)

Comment: It is simple, but not efficient for very large datasets.

Comment: Another quick question, in my post I left out some Where clausules because I thought they would be inserted easly but I can't get the job done. There are 2 other columns, season and round and I would like to add
    WHERE season = '2018/2019' AND round = 34
But I get an error that the column season isn't allright.
Any idea?

Comment: You must specify them in the select statement to use them in the where clause.

Comment: I tried this in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C1FxXFnt97HkTWhfRXHNx/5 but still getting the error "Unknown column 'tablename.season' in 'field list"

Comment: You can't do that. The code in my answer cannot be used to do something like this. The new columns may exist in the table but they do not exist in the query. In a group by statement you can only select the columns in the group by clause and aggregated columns like sum(), count() etc.

Comment: Tnx for clearing that out that this isn't possible. I am trying to do it with an IN subquery, hopefully this is the right way? The new query is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C1FxXFnt97HkTWhfRXHNx/7 but sadly enough I still got everytime an error, any idea how come? Normally I don't use these complex query's ... ;-)

Comment: I fixed the errors: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C1FxXFnt97HkTWhfRXHNx/8 although I'm not sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: Tnx for fixing the error, it almost does want I want to see .... ;-). I see that the COUNT function does make the count from the outer query but it really must do the count over the subquery as well so s4 must count 3 and s2 must count 2. E.g. the count must be done over the records where round = 34 and season is 2018/2019. I try to add a COUNT in the subquery but I get the same error as before.

Comment: The comments section is not the place to answer questions. You need to post a new question with all the relevant code, sample data, expected results and explain clearly what you want to do.

Comment: OK, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

@forpas answer is a good one. However, two things you should consider.

1. Due to the use of `union` the query will become slower as the data size increases.
2. If the input is as following:

```
s, s2, s3  
1, 2,  3  
4  
1, 3  
4, 2,  
2, 1  
3, 4  
4     5
```

The result of the provided query will be:

```
| s   | counter |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   | 3       |
| 2   | 3       |
| 3   | 3       |
| 4   | 4       |
| 5   | 1       |
```

whereas it should remain the same as 5 is not present into the s column.

In order to resolve both of the above issues, I propose the approach to use JOIN instead of UNION:

```
SELECT t3.s, IF(t3.s = t4.s3, cnt1 + 2, cnt1 + 1) as counter FROM 
    (SELECT *, count(*) AS cnt1 FROM 
        (SELECT s from table) AS t1 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT s2 FROM table) AS t2 
        ON t1.s = t2.s2 GROUP BY t1.s
    ) AS t3 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT s3 FROM table) AS t4 
    ON t3.s = t4.s3 
ORDER BY t3.s
```

The query might look a bit lengthy and complicated but it is really simple when you look into the logic.

**Step 1**
What I have done here is to make a left join from s column to s2 and counted results for that so it will give you 1 lesser number than how many numbers are present in total as it will make relation left to right.

**Step 2**
Then I have made a left join from s to s3, and only increase the count of step 1 by 1 if the relation is found.

**Step 3**
Ultimately I have increased the count by 1 so that we can convert the number of relations to the number of the enities.

*I hope it makes sense*

Comment: @forpas In the question, OP says: "I want to know how many times the unique values in column s appears in the columns s, s2 and s3", which emphasizes that we are only interested in the values of column s, so if some value is appearing in column s2 and s3 which are not present in column s, should simply be ignored

Comment: @Arie have my answer resolved your issue? if yes then please mark it accepted to close this thread on stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: why the negative vote? please always drop the comment whenever you give negative vote

Comment: I don't recall that I give a negative vote, I don't wanted to do that ;-)

Comment: @Arie Please note the issues I have mentioned when using the answer you have accepted. If it doesn't bother your need then all good. Just wanted to make you aware of that

Comment: @Learner you have 2 nested and and a 3d join in your code, an IF condition to check and you believe that this code will do better? I which universe? Your code is ugly and hard to maintain.

Comment: @Learner I understand that the Union solution can be a little bit slower with a lot of data but the table hasn't got a lot of records.

Comment: @forpas spoken like a professional. Arie, my bad. I thought the other solution also didnt fit all case scenarios.